# GraphQL mutation with subquery for parameter - update/convert DB on write?

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

Is it possible to add a look up to a mutation in GraphQL? Let's say something like an input type where one property is the result of another query.

```
createPerson(name: "Steve", gender: genders ( name: { eq: "mail" } ) { id } )
```

where `genders ( name: { eq: "mail" } ) { id }` would return exactly one result value

Comment: [almost] everything is possible... [ time and money limits ]... if supported by mutation resolver ... if not, simply query before mutation (2 requests)

Comment: I am trying to prefill a database and must query the keys of another table. I'd like to have this all in one file for the customer to be able to execute it

Comment: you don't need it at all ... just write an resolver for user\gender [query], it will be called when main user resolver won't read gender field ... in this resolver read other table, update user record and return value - next time value will be read with all user fields, gender resolver won't be called

Comment: This is not possible since it violates the GraphQL spec. Inputs are considered raw data so you cannot fill them with another field from your type.

Comment: @xadm Please post your comment as an answer, I'll accept then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphQL allows you to:

- "get what you want";
- manipulate data on write;
- customize response on read;

You can of course write a `createPerson` **mutation resolver** to:

- ask another table for additional data (if missing arg);
- write into DB;

But it doesn't affect (isn't suitable for) **existing records**.

You can also use **read resolvers** to update missing fields in records using field resolver - a kind of 'eventual consistency'.

Write person resolver to read a person record and additional `person.gender` field resolver to get value for missing `gender` value. The second one can be used to update the 'main' person [DB table] record:

- read a missing value from other table;
- write a value into person record on the 'main' table;
- return value.

**Next time** person resolver will read `gender` value at once (from 'main' person table), [additional] **field resolver won't be called at all**.

**This technique can be used to convert DB data** without writing SQL/DB specific code (different syntax/types problems, safer on more complex logic) - it's enough to read each/all person's `gender` fields. Field resolver (and the other/old table) can be removed after that.